# numpy.take range of array elements Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of integers.

```
data = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
```

I want to extract a range of integers from the array and get a smaller array.

```
data_extracted = [20,30,40]
```

I tried `numpy.take`.

```
data = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
start = 1    # index of starting data entry (20)
end = 3      # index of ending data entry (40)
data_extracted = np.take(data,[start:end])
```

I get a syntax error pointing to the `:` in numpy.take.

Is there a better way to use `numpy.take` to store part of an array in a separate array?

Comment: `data_extracted = data[1:3]`?

Comment: (where I was a bit too quick to assume you wanted the `start..<end` elements: for a slice over elements with indices 1 _through_ 3 (rather than _to_ 3), use `... = data[1:4]`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly slice the list.

```
import numpy as np
data = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
data_extracted = np.array(data[1:4])
```

Also, you do not need to use `numpy.array`, you could just store the data in another list:

```
data_extracted = data[1:4]
```

If you want to use `numpy.take`, you have to pass it a list of the desired indices as second argument:

```
import numpy as np
data = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
data_extracted = np.take(data, [1, 2, 3])
```

I do not think `numpy.take` is needed for this application though.

Comment: So numpy.take will not accept a range of values in colon notation?  In my actual scenario I select from 256 data points, so I was trying to use .take to make this more efficient.

Comment: @SpencerH. you could make use of `range(...)` as follows: `data_extracted = np.take(data, range(1, 4))`, which might be preferable over the explicit array of indices approach above (where the `range(...)` call yields a an integer sequence covering the half-open range over the two arguments, `range(from, to)` -> `[from, ..., to-1]`).

Comment: @Spencer H. It will accept a `range` as noted by dfri. You supplied a slice in your original example, which caused the syntax error, because there was nothing to slice. If you want to choose non continuous values, a `range` would not be preferred anymore. You should probably `idxlist.append(idx)` all the indices to another list and submit that second list with only the indices to `np.take(data, idxlist)` in that case.

Comment: @Tristan even a list of non-sequential indices might contain subranges that are better represented using `range` rather than explicitly listing all members of the subrange. You can still concenate the result(s) of the call to `range` to single non-sequential indices, e.g. `data_extracted = np.take(data, range(1, 4) + [5] + range(7,10))` will result in `[20,  30,  40,  60,  80,  90, 100]`.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to just use a slice to get a range of indices, there is no need for `numpy.take`, which is intended as a shortcut for fancy indexing.

```
data_extracted = data[1:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can use fancy indexing in this case. However, if you need to use np.take because e.g. the axis you're slicing over is variable, you might try:

```
axis=0
data.take(range(1,4), axis=axis)
```

Note: this might be slower than:
`data_extracted = data[1:4]`